# Data from Infopath drop down not showing in SharePoint List Views

Tags: infopath, list-view

I have setup a custom list (List A) with an InfoPath form to data connect to a different SharePoint list (List B). The form pulls into a cascading series of drop downs and returns user and address information.

My issue is that when a user saves the form and goes back to the SharePoint view (List A), the drop downs selected do not show up. However the view and edit view in InfoPath are populated correct.

Thanks

Comment: modify the view of the SharePoint list, make sure that there are no duplicate fields, maybe the InfoPath fields are different from the ones you see in the view